# Python3 PIL IMAGE module and metaclass

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, metaclass

I want to pass the class Image of the PIL module in one of my class, so I have naturally written :

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class BitsWindow(QtGui.QWidget, Image):
```

But I get this error :

class BitsWindow(QtGui.QWidget, Image):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

I have read on the net a few answer about this error but I don't really get it and I don't get why I have no problem using QT class the exact same way I try using PIL class...

Many Thanks
Blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image` is a module, not a class.

```
In [126]: type(Image)
Out[126]: module
```

A class is something that derives from `type`. `Image` does not derive from `type`:

```
In [128]: type(Image).__mro__
Out[129]: (module, object)
```

Thus, you can't use it as a base class:

```
In [127]: class BitsWindow(Image): pass
...
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

---

The error you are seeing,

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

is saying that all the bases of a class must have the same metaclass, or at least there must be an ordering of the metaclasses such that each is a subclass of the next. One derived class can not inherit two metaclasses, which makes sense since every class is an instance of its metaclass.

In your particular case, the error is raised because neither `type(Image)` nor `type(QWidget)` are subclasses of each other.

Comment: I thought Image was a class of the module PIL. So how do we use a module inside a class ? It seem my class don't know about PIL and Image, no problem outside it though

Comment: You can use the Image module inside the class the same way you would outside the class.

Comment: Ok, something is definitely wrong somewhere else in my code then, I know where (not) to look now, thank you very much for the explanation : )